# Please what means this

Tags: bash

Iam writting .sh script for uploading aplication on server and have correction of echo fail to download $...

```
c=country  like cz,us,sk etc
change of my echo fail to download $ on : echo cant find ${c^^}
```

```
Please, what means ${c^^} and ${c,,}
```

Thank you

Comment: That's bash parameter expansion syntax to uppercase and lowercase, respectively, the contents of $c. See [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the base manual

Comment: thank you very much for explanation